# How can we expose an endpoint from nuget, that can be used when we inject it as a middleware

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, nuget, asp.net-core-middleware

### Scenario

I have created a nuget package(a class library), which give two methods for the clients to use.
AddQueue() and RemoveQueue()
I have used this methods to create a HTTP Post and HTTP Delete endpoints respectively in the client project.

### What I want to achieve

I want the duty of endpoint creation to be done in the nuget itself. For example: If we inject UseSwaggerUI as a middleware in startup, it creates /swagger endpoint for us.
Same is the case with hangfire. I need my nuget to do the same thing.

Is there any way to achieve this? Any help would be greatful.
Thanks.

Comment: Can't your extension method by shipped along side the middleware so when you reference the package, you continue to do `app.UseMyMiddleware()` in startup as if the code is present in source form?